# Android EditText COMMA or DOT key event

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyevent

How can I detect comma or dot key event for a editText? I've tried using setOnKeyListener, but setOnKeyListener can detect digits, delete, done buttons not detecting comma and dot. I want to detect comma and dot key press event.

My XML looks like this:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal|number"
    android:digits="1234567890,."
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</EditText>
```

and my code is:

```
binding.edittext.setOnKeyListener { view, i, keyEvent ->
    Log.i(TAG,"edittext setOnKeyListener i -> $i keyevent $keyEvent")
    false
}
```

I can print every digits key events and delete key event except comma and dot key event
I don't know why but when I press comma(,) and dot(.) key from keyboard **setOnKeyListener** function not called.

Comment: Maybe better to use numberSigned instead of number?

Comment: @Yurii your comment is solution or just an advice?

Comment: So, you want to detect just the KEY event, or that comma has been written in EditText?

Comment: Yes I just want to detect Key Event nothing else.

Answer (score -1):

According to official doc: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/keyboard-input/commands

> Note: When handling keyboard events with the KeyEvent class and related APIs, expect that the keyboard events are coming only from a hardware keyboard. Never rely on receiving key events for any key on a soft input method (an on-screen keyboard).

Better to use TextWatcher https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher to handle this two symbols by hand.

Comment: This solution not suitable for me because my edit text is more complicated. As I say before I just want to detect Key Event.

Comment: Ok, but I send official doc and it is right answer, because better to use text watcher in this case, just google it on stack and there is no way to check it through the key codes.

Comment: you firstly said 'right answer' and after that you said 'better to use' that why your answer not helping to my question.

Comment: You said, you "Yes I just want to detect Key Event nothing else." And I sen you official doc, about that Android not guaranteed that it will works as expected.

Comment: BTW if you are pretty sure this is the answer than you may say 'android not support key event for comma and dot. That's why may help this solution for you' but I'm talking about complety different problem